# How do I get the dialer to open with phone number displayed?

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-number

I don't need to call the phone number, I just need the dialer to open with the phone number already displayed. What `Intent` should I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 615, accepted):

Two ways to achieve it.

**1) Need to start the dialer via code, without user interaction.**

You need `Action_Dial`,

use below code  it will open Dialer with number specified

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
startActivity(intent);
```

**The 'tel:' prefix is required**, otherwhise the following exception will be thrown:
*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity.*

**Action_Dial doesn't require any permission.**

**If you want to initiate the call directly without user's interaction** , You can use action `Intent.ACTION_CALL`. In this case, you must add the following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

**2) Need user to click on Phone_Number string and start the call.**

```
android:autoLink="phone"
```

You need to use TextView with below property.

[android:autoLink="phone"
android:linksClickable="true" a textView property](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:autoLink)

You don't need to use intent or to get permission via this way.

Comment: That is great and it differs than Intent.ACTION_CALL by that it doesn't call immediately

Comment: Does ACTION_DIAL requires the permission, or only ACCESS_CALL does?

Comment: rather than open a new queston, how would open the dialer and start the call (so you can have dialer options), just starting the call gives you no options for stop, speaker etc..

Comment: This **works** with phone numbers from **Denmark** as well :) You **do not need** to add +45 before the number. It works fine just parsing the phone number

Comment: DOn't forget to add the following flag to your ACTION_DIAL intent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET. This will reset your task when you launch into your app again, and won't launch into the dialler by mistake.

Comment: Ive got problem with back button after opening dialer in new intent. I can get back to my application only in 3 back button press (it shows me several screens of dialer which I didnt open - the dialer itself, create new contact screen, favourites). Does somebody knows how to get back to app with only 1 back button press?

Comment: @kashlo did you find solution for this?

Comment: @AndréVicente Ive asked a question about this problem, see the comment
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40220279/how-to-open-dialer-and-get-back-to-your-app-in-one-step-in-android

Comment: 2012... Good old days. It's politically correct 2018, big companies sell of user data and our apps need to deal with Android bureaucracy just to NOT support SMS and Phone calls.

Answer (score 57):

Pretty late on the answer, but if you have a `TextView` that you're showing the phone number in, then you don't need to deal with intents at all, you can just use the XML attribute `android:autoLink="phone"` and the OS will automatically initiate an `ACTION_DIAL` Intent.

Comment: Very fast approach!

Answer (score 21):

Okay, it is going to be extremely late answer to this question. But here is just one sample if you want to do it in **Kotlin**.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
intent.data = Uri.parse("tel:<number>")
startActivity(intent)
```

Thought it might help someone.

Answer (score 3):

You can call Intent following this:

```
String number = "0123456789";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

As @ashishduh mentioned above, using `android:autoLink="phone` is also a good solution. But this option comes with one drawback, it doesn't work with all phone number lengths. For instance, a phone number of 11 numbers won't work with this option. The solution is to prefix your phone numbers with the country code.

Example:

`08034448845` won't work

but `+2348034448845` will

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
 android:autoLink="phone"
 android:linksClickable="true"
 android:text="+91 22 2222 2222"
 />
```

This is how you can open EditText label assigned number on dialer directly.

Answer (score 1):

A helper function for someone using kotlin:

```
fun openDialPad(context: Context, phoneNum: String) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:$phoneNum"))
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```