# How to open the desired number in android phone application?

Tags: android

I tried with this code, but it is not that I expect:

```
textView.setText("0 (800) 701 201");
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
```

result:

[image]

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699819/how-do-i-get-the-dialer-to-open-with-phone-number-displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are trying to make a call. Launch the intent to call like this...

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9876543210");
startActivity(i);
```

Good Luck :)