# Android Intent call number

Tags: android, phone-call

I have my phone number at `TextView` and want to open "Intent-picker" to choose application that I want to call with(Skype, Viber...) or just dial to call it.

`Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);` calls instantly so it doesn't help me.

Comment: "want to open "Intent-picker" to choose application or just dial to call it" -- choose what? "...calls instantly so it doesn't help me" -- use `ACTION_DIAL`.

Comment: There are lots of apps that provide calls. So want to choose from them and basic calling function.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
startActivity(intent);
```

This opens the dialer (or creates a chooser dialog if there are multiple apps installed which can place a phone call) with the number filled in, but does not actually start the call. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11699829/4428462) for more info.

Answer (score 9):

**Official Solution**

Example intent:

```
public void dialPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For kotlin

```
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
    intent.data = Uri.parse("tel:0123456789")
    startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Nice for Kotlin!