# cannot open USSD syntax from webview in android

Tags: html, web, href, progressive-web-apps, tel

I'm working on a Vue app progressive-web-apps and I have a specific tel syntax like

`href="tel:#000*01010101#"`

but when I click on the link, it opens the phone dial pad with only the # character showing.

I tried to encode the uri with  `encodeURI("tel:#000*01010101#")` but same thing. also the %23 which corresponds to # character and same thing with ascii

tried solution :

- [tel: link not working on Android when anonymous call code #31# is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51019518/tel-link-not-working-on-android-when-anonymous-call-code-31-is-used)

phone screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-telephone-links/

Maybe try parsing the telephone number in the NNN-NNN-NNNN format? Also, you number is 11 digits, not 10.

Not sure, but try it both with and without the hashtags (#) at the ends.

So something like this:

`href="tel:000-010-1010"`

Tried it using w3schools, worked.

Comment: thanks for your answer but don't it resolve my issue it's not only a phone number but a complete phone operator syntax who perform aGSM operation so it's necessary to me to include the # character and that at the start and at the end.