# Redirect mobile number in the app directly to the dialer?

Tags: android-studio

How to redirect the mobile number given in the android application on the button click to the phone dialer in the mobile phone?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699819/how-do-i-get-the-dialer-to-open-with-phone-number-displayed

Comment: @TilakMadichetti                                                                                                          **Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
startActivity(intent);**  in the above code I am getting an error in the last line