# How to open dialer and get back to your app in one step in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my application I have a button with telephone number, and when user clicks on it the Dialer app is opened with the number in phone field. However if I want to get back from dialer to my app I should press 'Back' button 3 times. First press closes the dialer keyboard, second press brings me to dialer history menu, and only 3 press reopens my app. Is it possible to get back in 1 back button press?

Here is my button OnClickListener

```
vPhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Simple Answer **NO** , but you can use `Intent.ACTION_CALL` , which will make the call directly, and ending it should take you back to the app itself

Comment: @kashlo did you find workaround?

Comment: @user1221256 no, I just left as it is, 3 steps back