# How to call on a Number Directly from Android App

Tags: android, android-intent, call

I want to open a Calling Screen Directly from my app, I searched a lot about  on internet and getting no success. Code i am following to call a number from android app is as follows :

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL).setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNo)));
```

in `Manifest` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

but this code is showing Choose Action Window and I don't want to show this window :

[image]

Is it possible to open Phone call app directly rather than open Action Window ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26783528/2308683

Comment: "I don't want to show this window" -- first, what if the user wants to use Skype? Second, there are ~2 billion Android devices, from thousands of device models, and manufacturers can replace "Phone call app". How do you intend to identify "Phone call app" from any other `ACTION_CALL` handler?

Comment: @CommonsWare i am working on a app from which user will be able to call on number if he tap on a widget , dont want skype call as a option.

Comment: @KapilRajput Some people use Skype for regular calls..

Comment: You as the developer shouldn't decide what the user wants. Say you run your app on a tablet. It has no phone app, but what if Skype is installed there and the user has no other option?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot my question is not to show skype as a option like for an example if user want to call on dominos or any other number where there is no role of skype call then why to show him skype as a option ?

Comment: @cricket_007 my question is not to show skype as a option like for an example if user want to call on dominos or any other number where there is no role of skype call then why to show him skype as a option ?

Comment: Skype only appears because it's installed. Test your app on an emulator or different device

Comment: @KapilRajput Because Skype allows **phone calls**.  https://www.skype.com/en/features/call-phones-and-mobiles/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately (or really not) you can't. This is security measure. You can't directly open some app, because in 70% cases (just my results after testing) it will give you Security error.

### Some clarification

As mentioned in comments you can define package in Intent. But it's really unhealthy behavior. For example

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("test@gmail.com"));
    sendIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, getSelectedContactsEmails().toArray());
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subj");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
    startActivityForResult(sendIntent,0);
```

This code will call directly GMail app. But it have unpredictable behavior  . In my case I got crash on one Nexus 5, but all worked on another one. Also you need to add additional code to ensure, that package is installed.

In your case you need to call some phone app. Do you know Android device fragmentation? There are 10000+ different devices and all of them can have different packages for calling. So do you really need it?

In fact there is even special method, that will handle selection of app you need by system

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail via ...")); //example
```

This code won't get you Security error ever, because user actions are perceived by system "as a truth"

### Clarification 2

Yes, you can cycle through all packages that can accept your intent. *Yes*, you can even call random(or pre-defined) package and *yes*, it might work is some cases. But **some** doesn't mean **all** and there is a problem. And if there any chance that app will crash on some device, you need to avoid it by any means.

Comment: That's not a security dialog. All those apps have an Intent filter for calling. You can hard-code the package name of any Intent to start one app

Comment: @cricket_007 and you'll get so many Security errors, that will be enough for the end of your life.

Comment: If you could provide an example in your post, that'd be great

Comment: where does this 70% come from?

Comment: @TimCastelijns just testing here and there with this code (percentage of testing devices that crashed)

Comment: in other words, this percentage has no meaning

Comment: @TimCastelijns yep. Just scary number.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a package name for your intent and directly call an application

```
intent.setPackage("com.android.phone");
```