# Dialing a short number when I click on the TextView

Tags: android

I need to open the dial action when I click on `TextView`, but this does not happen. With a long number in the international format, everything is OK. Tell me how to solve the problem?

```
TextView phoneNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.companyPhoneNumber);
phoneNumber.setText("7040");
phoneNumber.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

XML:

```
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/companyPhoneNumber"
 style="@style/tvs_company_info_text_blue"
 android:autoLink="phone"
 android:text="@string/txt_companyinfo_phone_number"/>
```

P.S. How to solve the problem using Intent.ACTION_DIAL or Intent.ACTION_CALL I know. I'm interested in how to solve it through Linkify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the dialer to open with phone number displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699819/how-do-i-get-the-dialer-to-open-with-phone-number-displayed)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + your_number);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: Are you sure that with permissions will be good?  Through Linkify in any way?

Comment: `android:autoLink="phone"` in this,Its not taking more than 10 digits

Comment: @EfremovAV `android:autoLink="phone"` not work if textview has more than 10 digits

Comment: 7040  - it's 4 digits

Comment: @EfremovAV ,Its working for 4 digits when i tried your code.

Comment: Did you try above solution??

Comment: How to solve the problem using Intent.ACTION_DIAL or Intent.ACTION_CALL I know. I'm interested in how to solve it through Linkify.

Comment: Your solution works, I have a question why it does not work through link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161798/discussion-between-kamal-verma-and-efremovav).