# How to use default dialer screen in android?

Tags: android, android-dialer

I am developing an UI for the voip project. I have designed a UI for the dialer screen. Is it possible to use default dialer screen in android project? If yes please provide a link to refer.

Comment: i don't understand properly can you provide screen short what you can do ?

Comment: I have created an activity which has dialer pad to type phone numbers and make calls. Is it possible to use the default dialer activity of android

Comment: Duplicate Question https://stackoverflow.com/q/11699819/5370550 Do some research before asking questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is there your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11699829/10967323) ?

Comment: You can find my accepted answer here

Comment: as well my above comment your answer done.

Comment: Yeah!! that's also correct. Thank you for spending your valuable time for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use default dialer of your phone just use below code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "1234567890"));
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
```

You have to mention the number on which you want to place the call. It will open default dialer screen