# Flutter url_launcher Unhandled Exception: Could not launch youtube url (Caused by canLaunch)

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use the `url_launcher` plugin to open youtube videos by link but the `canLaunch` function keeps throwing an error. I'm able to bypass this error only by completely removing the `canLaunch` function but can't figure out what is wrong.

Code not working:

```
_goToVideo(YoutubeVideoData video) async {
  if (await canLaunch(video.url)) {
    await launch(video.url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch ${video.url}';
  }
}
```

Code working:

```
_goToVideo(YoutubeVideoData video) async {
  await launch(video.url);
}
```

I'm not quite sure why I can't use the `canLaunch` method as written in the [README Example](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#url_launcher)

Error:

```
E/flutter (12574): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: Could not launch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3g5WlqJtIo
E/flutter (12574): #0      _goToVideo (package:esfandapp/widgets/newsList/videoCard.dart:71:5)
E/flutter (12574): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12574): #1      VideoCard.build.<anonymous closure> (package:esfandapp/widgets/newsList/videoCard.dart:13:20)
E/flutter (12574): #2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:992:19)
E/flutter (12574): #3      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1098:38)
E/flutter (12574): #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:184:24)
E/flutter (12574): #5      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:524:11)
E/flutter (12574): #6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:284:5)
E/flutter (12574): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:256:7)
E/flutter (12574): #8      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:158:27)
E/flutter (12574): #9      GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:224:20)
E/flutter (12574): #10     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:200:22)
E/flutter (12574): #11     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:7)
E/flutter (12574): #12     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:104:7)
E/flutter (12574): #13     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:88:7)
E/flutter (12574): #14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter (12574): #15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (12574): #16     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (12574): #17     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:267:10)
E/flutter (12574): #18     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:176:5)
```

Widget using the function:

```
class VideoCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final YoutubeVideoData video;
  VideoCard({this.video});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => _goToVideo(video),
      child: Container(
        child: Card(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Align(
                  child: Padding(
                    child: Text(
                      video.title,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Roboto Condensed',
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 15, 10),
                  ),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                ),
                Container(
                    child: Image.network(video.thumbnails[1], fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                ),
                Align(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(
                      video.date.toString() + "",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Roboto Condensed',
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                      ),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 5, 15, 0),
                  ),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 32,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 0,
              vertical: 10,
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25))),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Starting from API30 (Android 11), your Android app has to list all apps it interacts with.

You can add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

in your android manifest to bypass it or specifically list them.

For more info:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility

Comment: Be very careful with permission "QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES". Google Play is starting to restrict it on May 5, 2021 and you app may be removed from the store: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779

Answer (score 74):

Personally, I don't like the uncertainty that seems to come with using the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission (because Google could stop letting people use it in the future). For that reason, I did some investigation and found that adding the following to my AndroidManifest.xml allows my app to open the browser, phone app and email app on API 30:

```
<manifest>

    <!-- Nest within the manifest element, not the application element-->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application>
        ....
    </application>
</manifest>
```

To get the same functionality working on iOS, it may be necessary to add the following to your info.plist file:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>https</string>
    <string>http</string>
    <string>tel</string>
    <string>mailto</string>
</array>
```

Just wanted to share in case it helps someone else out.

Comment: Thank you. My Android app didn't work without these settings. Do we have such a setting for iOS? I am testing on iPhone 12 Pro max emulator. My URLs can be opened but not Phone and email. So, I am wondering is there such a setting for iOS, too?

Comment: No problem @Hesam, I have updated my answer with iOS-specific info

Comment: thanks for updating your answer. I added those things but phone and email still don't work on the emulator although it works on the actual device. I am not an iOS developer so I am wondering is it an emulator issue or is a common issue for iOS developers.

Comment: Hi @Hesam, yes I seem to remember from my testing that phone calls and email are not supported by the Xcode simulator. The following links agree with this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3830910 and https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/mobile-apps/the-ios-simulators-limitations/. Were phone calls and email working on your actual device before you added the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes to your info.plist file?

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'...The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.


Getting this error after adding the above lives in manifest tag in android.

Comment: Hi @Apoorvpandey, I've never seen this error before. After doing a bit of research, it seems like one possible cause could be an open file handle on one of the files in your build directory, as per this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674224/6630965). Please try deleting your build directory and retrying. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, this worked. I had to delete the build and do one or two things here and there in the app.

Comment: I have a problem that the phone app is launched with the number written but it's not called, I have to click on the dial to make the call.
is that what the package should do?

Comment: @Shalabyer, in the past I remember that clicking on a phone number would cause a call to be made immediately on iOS and Android, but I believe it is now standard behaviour on both platforms to just open the phone app with the number (probably so that you users don't make calls by mistake). I tested this on both an Android and iOS phone by searching for a local restaurant on Google and pressing the 'Call' button. On both iOS and Android, I experienced the behaviour that you describe. So I believe this behaviour is controlled by the OS, not the package.

Comment: Great I used both go the above but this answer is better because of googles policies, thanks!

Comment: It's better than using QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES for google limitations

Answer (score 9):

Even after trying accepted answer, If its not working for you then Please try followed code.

**PRE STEPS:** Do as accepted answer suggested.

Add following tags in **AndroidManifest.xml** before `<application/>`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>

<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

**NOW WHAT I HAVE DONE**

Create one method:

```
Future<void> _makeSocialMediaRequest(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

and Called it by following way:

```
  //FOR EMAIL
  final Uri _emailLaunchUri = Uri(
      scheme: 'mailto',
      path: 'pratik13butani@gmail.com',
      queryParameters: {'subject': 'Pratik Butani'});
  _makeSocialMediaRequest(_emailLaunchUri.toString());

  //FOR PHONE NUMBER:
  final Uri _phoneLaunchUri =
      Uri(scheme: 'tel', path: postOffice.mobileNo);
  _makeSocialMediaRequest(_phoneLaunchUri.toString());

  //FOR ANY URL.. YOU CAN PASS DIRECT URL..
  _makeSocialMediaRequest("http://pratikbutani.com");
```

Its working for me. Hopefully it will work for you too. Thank you.

Comment: I have a problem that the phone app is launched with the number written but it's not called, I have to click on the dial to make the call.
is that what the package should do?

Answer (score 7):

bro only put '!' before "if (!await canLaunch(url))"
Use this -->

```
 if (!await canLaunch(url)){
  await launch(
    url,
    forceSafariVC: false,
    forceWebView: false,
    headers: <String, String>{'my_header_key': 'my_header_value'},
  );
} else {
  
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```

Comment: It.. worked for me? - but then you can just remove the "canLaunch" altogether. Is `canLaunch` broken?

Comment: Took almost an hour to find this simple solution.. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For **Android** Use the below code in `Android/main/res/AndroidManifest.xml` like the showed in the image

[image]

and here is the code

```
<intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent>
<intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent>
<intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
</intent>
```

For **IPhone** `ios/Runner/Info.plist` like the showed in the image

[image]

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>https</string>
    <string>http</string>
    <string>tel</string>
    <string>mailto</string>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to add in the android manifest the below line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

Don't forget about the Info.plist as well

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>https</string>
    <string>http</string>
    <string>tel</string>
    <string>mailto</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 2):

I spent nearly 2 hours to find what is wrong and after I closed the application from the recent tab and re-run the app it worked perfectly fine.

Things you might missed,

1. adding Url_launcher dependency in pubspec.yaml
2. Adding queries in Android manifest file after tag

```html
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

3. Adding keys in the info.plist file under ios directory

```html
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>https</string>
    <string>http</string>
</array>
```

4. Just try to uninstall app and run the code

Answer (score 0):

i faced same error using win and linux for android developments
and solve it with these steps
the idea is to add the  to AndroidManifest.xml in app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
to do so and to make it work without error you must update the gardle version so here is the steps
1-updated my gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-6.7.1-all.zip

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```

2- updated my classpath  in  android/build.gradle to com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

3- add the  above  to my AndroidManifest.xml in app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <queries>
        <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app makes calls -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app emails -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

and now everything work fine

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above works, try adding this in the AndroidManifest.xml (main one if you have that). Add this code snipped just above the `<application>` tag.

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
      await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url),
      mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication, );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Android** Just add in your androidmanifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

For **iOS** add these in your info.plist file

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>https</string>
    <string>http</string>
    <string>tel</string>
    <string>mailto</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

`QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` **(not recommended)**

Because Google could stop letting people use it in the future as mentioned in the official [document](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring)

if you use launch any url from your app just use

```
<manifest package="com.example.game">
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.android.chrome" />
        
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

likewise you can add `<queries>` depends on your need.

> ex.

```
<queries>
        <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app makes calls -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app emails -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

Answer (score -4):

This worked for me

```
if (!url.contains('http')) url = 'https://$url';
```

Complete Method:

```
launchURL(String url) async {
  if (!url.contains('http')) url = 'https://$url';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```