# How to resolve could not launch Error in Url launcher

Tags: flutter, dart, url-launcher

I am trying open a link on Google pixel API 30 Emulator but keep on getting error. Have tried flutter clean, restarted app.

Dependency:-

```
url_launcher: ^6.0.3
```

Code:-

```
  InkWell(
onTap:() => _launchURL("https://google.com"),
child: Image.asset("assets/images/googleIcon.jpg")
),

_launchURL(String url) async {
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(url);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```

}

Error:-

```
   Unhandled Exception: Could not launch https://google.com
```

Comment: Show your code inside `_launchURL()`

Comment: Done, Thanks to this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63625023/flutter-url-launcher-unhandled-exception-could-not-launch-youtube-url-caused-b/65082750

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68611830/6666348

Answer (score 0):

Add a URI class since url_launcher recommends encoding the URLs as URI. [Link to Doc](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#encoding-urls)

```dart
final Uri _faireGitHubUri = Uri.https('google.com', '/');

    InkWell(
onTap:() => _launchURL(_websiteUri.toString()),
child: Image.asset("assets/images/googleIcon.jpg")
),
```