# How to open URL in flutter app with url_launcher?

Tags: flutter, dart, url, url-launcher

I use the package url_launcher to open url, here is the code:

```
  Future <void> _openURL(String url) async{
    if(await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(
          url,
        forceSafariVC: false,
        forceWebView: true,
      );
    }
    else{
      throw 'Cant open URL';
    }
  }


ListTile(
                        title: Text('Google'),
                        onTap: () {
                          _openURL('https://www.google.de/');
                        }),
```

But no matter what url i want to open, i get the error 'Cant open URL'

Comment: it works in my case, which device you are trying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get the same error: Unhandled Exception: Could not launch

As you can see here https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher you have to put the following snippet at your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<queries>
  <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: At what point in the manifest should we place it?

Comment: @Lefty As a child of `manifest` and a sibling of `uses-permission`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to below code:

Create launchURL function :

```
_launch() async {
    const url = 'https://www.google.de/';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Create your Widget :

```
ListTile(
     onTap: _launch,
     title: Text('Google'),
    ),
```

Hope its solved your problem

Comment: what was the problem

Comment: I get the same error: Unhandled Exception: Could not launch https://www.google.de/

Comment: try to exit and relaunch app or  run commands `flutter clean` then  `flutter pub get` then run your app

Comment: It still dont work, I have no idea whats wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235509/discussion-between-ravindra-s-patil-and-dalon).

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to open the URL in Android using Flutter app with pub file `https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher`

Since JavaScript was not enable.

Here's working code snippet for Android  -

```
  void _launchURL(String _url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(_url)) {
      await launch(_url, forceSafariVC: true, forceWebView: true, enableJavaScript: true);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $_url';
    }
  }
```

Then I added a key `enableJavaScript: true` and it started working on Android too. iOS no need for configuration.