# What happens when you click on a URL link and the link opens the app instead in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a link to a website but I want when the user clicks on the link, they are taken to the app instead of the browser.

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69465730/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68610133/13997210)  hope its helful to you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using device_apps [Flutter_device_apps](https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps#open-an-application) (not supported for **IOS**).

Answer (score 0):

[firebase_dynamic_links](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links) package can help you in this regards.

With Dynamic Links, your users get the best available experience for the platform they open your link on. If a user opens a Dynamic Link on *iOS* or *Android*, they can be taken directly to the linked content in your native app. If a user opens the same Dynamic Link in a desktop browser, they can be taken to the equivalent content on your website.