# how to redirect specific link to your app similar to whatsapp

Tags: flutter, hyperlink

how to create your app's link? like WhatsApp. if you click on this link https://wa.me/546497546464
that link takes you to WhatsApp app in your phone. like how to create a link that takes user to specific screen in your app?
*-*-*in flutter*-*-*

Comment: You can use dynamic link as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called Deep Linking

The following from https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking

#### Enable deep linking on Android

Add a metadata tag and intent filter to `AndroidManifest.xml` inside the `<activity>` tag with the ".MainActivity" name:

```xml
<!-- Deep linking -->
<meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="flutterbooksample.com" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

#### Enable deep linking on iOS

Add two new keys to `Info.plist` in the ios/Runner directory:

```xml
<key>FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Editor</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string>flutterbooksample.com</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
    <string>customscheme</string>
    </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you,Used `url_launcher` package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) add this dependency in your `pubspec.yaml` file

**Your Widget**

```
InkWell(
      hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: Image.network('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5e/WhatsApp_icon.png',
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
      ),
      onTap: () => _whatsApp(),
    )
```

**Create ontap function**

```
_whatsApp() async {
    const url =
        'https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=546497546464&text&app_absent=0';// or add your URL here
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

You also refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68610133/13997210) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69465730/13997210) for `url_launcher`

Comment: no no. i mean how to open a specific screen in my app using the url. look how whatsapp is doing. like if i click on WhatsApp link https://wa.me/546497546464 it open the WhatsApp app in my phone .

Comment: i mean how to open my app with URL.

Comment: can you tell me you can try my answer and test it on your device? its way to open app using url

Comment: yes, I did, I wanted to redirect a link to my app, not redirecting from my app to another app. I got my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69793981/17286853. thank you too