# how to share a product from your e commerce app

Tags: flutter, hyperlink, share

is there a way to share my e-commerce app products? like the amazon app. when you click on share. it makes a URL for you, and you can send the URL to everyone.

[image]

and if you click on share it gives you this link.

[image]

can anyone please help me on how to share my e-commerce app's products

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will have to use two packages for this...
[dynamic plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links)
[share plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/share)

```
1. dynamic link 
2. share
```

you use the dynamic link to generate the short link of the product then use share to share it to users. so if user click on it it will automatic bring them to the production...
[dynamic video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLBjAg6HvG0&t=684s)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have a route to your product in your app. You probably already have that. If not, you need to build that. There are really too many ways to do that and the one to pick depends on what you did so far in your app and how you handle navigation.

Assuming you are at a point where you can create a link to a product by hand, you can use [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) to open the device/platform specific sharing dialog in your application and share that link. Check out their [example](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus/example) and go from there.