# flutter open facebook messenger

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to open facebook messenger using urllauncher as follow. But I can't launch a messenger.

I can open facebook page, youtube and even call phone using urllaucher.

```
OutlinedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    //_launchURL(about.messenger!,);
                    await canLaunch("https://m.me/myfacebookname")
                        ? await launch("https://m.me/myfacebookname", forceWebView: false)
                        : throw 'Could not launch ${"https://m.me/myfacebookname"}';
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.messenger_outline_sharp),
                  label: const AutoSizeText(""),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69465730/13997210) or 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68610133/13997210) hope it's helpful to you. In this answers I have open LinkedIn app and Google just changed your url with LinkedIn instead of messanger

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I think that I did the same thing. I can open facebook and youtube but I can't open facebook messenger.

Answer (score 0):

I need to add queries tab in Minifest. I thought I don't need it because I can open facebook.

```
<queries>
      <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
      <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
      </intent>
      <!-- If your app makes calls -->
      <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
      </intent>
      <!-- If your app emails -->
      <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
      </intent>
    </queries>
```

Comment: Where to put this... in <application> or <activity> etc...

Comment: Just outside the <applicaiton>. I put under <manifest>

Answer (score 0):

this is how I opened facebook messenger from my flutter app.
I created a function as follow.

```
launchMessenger(){
 String facebookIdHere=myfacebookId;
 String url() {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    String uri = 'fb-messenger://user/$facebookIdHere';
    return uri;
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    // iOS
    String uri = 'https://m.me/$facebookIdHere';
    return uri;
  }
  else{
    return 'error';
  }
}

if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url()))) {
  await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url()));
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch ${url()}';
}}
```

then on the button I called the function.

```
FloatingActionButton(
onPressed:(){launchMessenger();})
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I did not test for IOS. So I don't know if it works or not.